# Handling Periodic celery tasks in a Disaster Recovery setup

Tags: django, kubernetes, celery, openshift, gslb

I am having a web application named WEB_APP. This web application is deployed in 3 datacenters, WEB_APP_1, WEB_APP_2, WEB_APP_3. WEB_APP is a django rest framework based application which has a few periodic celery tasks running in the background and also make changes to the database.

WEB_APP_1, WEB_APP_2 and WEB_APP_3 all point to the same database.

The periodic celeries run in all 3 datacenters and cause changes to the database multiple times.

Is there a way to make the periodic celeries active only for the datacenter web app which is pointed by the GSLB?